# Join Result Sets Mechanism

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Look at a simple `sql` code:

```
declare @t1 table (id int);
insert into @t1(id) values(1),(2),(3);
select * from @t1

declare @t2 table (id int);
insert into @t2(id) values(9);
select * from @t2

select * from @t1, @t2; -- q1

select ds1.id from @t1 as ds1, (select id from @t2) as ds2 -- q2
```

Why result of `q1` and `q2` is different, aren't they supposed to be same?

Comment: You should look at second query you are selecting just one col that is from `@t1` not from `@t2`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma both t1 and t2 have same column name i.e. id.

Comment: But your alise is saying to read data from `@t1`.

Comment: select 2, (select 4) -- q1
select x from (select 2 as x union select 3) as ds1, (select 4 as y) as ds2 -- q2
@YogeshSharma ... look at this, it may help u understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t1 table (id int);
insert into @t1(id) values(1),(2),(3);
select * from @t1

declare @t2 table (id int);
insert into @t2(id) values(9);
select * from @t2

select * from @t1, @t2; -- q1
select ds1.id from @t1 as ds1, (select id from @t2) as ds2
```

In this scenario, `(select id from @t2) as ds2` is considered as a derived table. You didn't fetch the column in your query.

Try this:

```
select ds1.id,ds2.id 
from @t1 as ds1, 
  (select id from @t2) as ds2 -- q2
```

**OutPut:**

```
id  id
1   9
2   9
3   9
```